# Public transportation from Frankfurt Hahn towards Koenigstein (Taunus)

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, hhn

I am trying to find a way to check the public transportation offer from Fraknfurt Hahn airport to Koenigstein (Taunus) but it seems that this data does not exist in public search engines.

Any ideas on where to search?

Comment: Frankfurt Hahn is simply not in Frankfurt at all and as such not part of its public transit system. I am also told it's poorly connected to the German public transportation network in general but others might be able to give more details.

Comment: That is likely to help you: http://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_bus&cc=en However, I can't seem to find any place called Frankfurt Koenigstein or Koeningstein. You might refer to Koenigstein am Taunus? Because apparently the reason why you can't this data is you're trying to go to some unexisting place.

Comment: Stadt: Koenigstein
Postleitzahl: 61462

Comment: Am I doing some spelling error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the zip code you gave (=Postleitzahl) you want to reach Koenigstein im Taunus. This is accessible from Hahn airport, even though it is not the easiest and fastest trip.

I could search it on the [Deutsche Bahn](http://www.bahn.de) and found a possible connection. You have to take the Bus 600 to Frankfurt Main station (Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof in German, sometimes shortened in Hbf). The ride is quite long, about 1h45. Then you can take a train from Frankfurt Main Station, Koenigstein im Taunus being the last stop of that train (apparently the train often leaves from platform 22 or 23). The ride is less than 30 minutes but the connection can be longer, there is apparently one train per hour.

Regarding the price I could not find information though.

[image: screenshot of Deutsche Bahn]

Note: also note that while the [bus 600 from Hahn](http://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_bus&cc=en) stops at main Frankfurt airport which is better served by public transportation, stopping there is not a better alternative as it takes 1h30 for Hahn-Main airport.

Comment: Is there a wp8 application that I can use, since I am the owner of a nokia lumia 620?

Comment: @skiabox have you even looked for the Deutsche Bahn app before asking? There is an Android app at least for the Deutsche Bahn, I'll let you search for Windows Phone.